# ng-repeat on multiple arrays

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there a way to loop through multiple arrays in an ng-repeat directive ?

I tried something like

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="sale in randomSales" ng-repeat="image in imageUrls">
        <div display-sale></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="sale in randomSales, image in imageUrls">
        <div display-sale></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

but it's not working.

I could solve this issue another way, but I'd like to know if this is possible !

EDIT : 
Here is my controller & directive :

```
    app.controller('RandomController', ['$rootScope', '$scope',function($rootScope, $scope) {
        $scope.randomSales=[];
        $scope.imageUrls = [];
        for(var i= 0; i < displayrandomSalesNumber ; i++){
            var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * $rootScope.sales.length-1) + 1);
            $scope.randomSales.push($rootScope.sales[randomNumber]);
            $scope.imageUrls.push($rootScope.sales[randomNumber].image_urls["300x280"][0].url);
        }
        console.log($scope.randomSales);
    }])
        .directive('displaySale', function() {
        return {
            template:   '<div class="center"><a href="#/sale/{{sale.store}}/{{sale.sale_key}}">' +
                            '<header><h2>{{sale.name}}</h2><h4>in {{sale.store}}</h4></header>' +
                            '<article>' +
                                '<p>From : {{sale.begins}} To : {{sale.ends}}</p>' +
                                '<p class="center"><img  ng-src="{{image}}"/></p>' +
                                '<p>{{sale.description}}</p>' +
                            '</article>' +
                        '</a></div>'
        };
    });
```

the image is already inside $scope.randomSales, I could access it with {{sale.image_urls["300x280"][0].url}} but i'd get a parse error.

Comment: No, it's not. You've not said what you wanted to achieve, BTW. Do you want to display an li for each sale, then a li for each image? If so, just use 2 ng-repeat, orconcatenate the arrays into a single one. Do you want to display an li for each pair of sae/image? If so you should have an array of pairs of sale/image.

Comment: can you define the relationship between sale & image?? are they unrelated or they share some relationship??

Comment: yes they are related, I'll edit my post to add the directive and explanations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to make it work you can try to do following: 
 - merge 2 arrays to one arrays of objects representing imageUrls and randomSales. 
 - iterate though them in your template.

For example:

```
var maxArrayLength = Math.max(randomSales.length, imageUrls.length);
var i = 0;
var result = []; //will put items  {sale: ..., image}
for (i =0; i < maxArrayLength; i++){
   var currentSale = randomSales[i] != null ? randomSales[i] : null;
   var currentImage = imageUrls[i] != null ? imageUrls[i] : null;
   result.push({sale: currentSale, image: currentImage})
}
return result;
```

And them you can use this array to iterate through on your angular template.

Comment: Yes, I thought about something like this, I guess it will be my solution if I can't get the image url directly inside the directive

Answer (score 2):

The First Solution proposed by you is wrong , we cant have two ng-repeat attributes in one Html tag, I am not sure about the second one . But you could try like this ..i think it would work.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="sale in randomSales">
       <span ng-repeat="image in imageUrls">
        <div display-sale></div>
       </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I used your solution in other part of my code to test it, it works, too bad I can't set best answer for 2 people